# Storing Data on JBoss

Tags: apache, jboss, application-server, data-synchronization

I want to offer files on an Apache-Server (A).
I want to Upload them through a PrimeFaces frontend with a JBoss-Server.
Now I am instructed to pass these through to another Apache-Server (B).
I would implement a Synchronization between (A) and (B).

These files will be about 1gb of size and could be automatically deleted as soon as they are stored on (A).

Couldn't I store the Files temporarily on the JBoss-Server and synchronize this one with (A)? The data will pass through it anyway and JBOSS and (B) will be on the same physical machine anyway.
This way I wouldn't need (B) at all. It seems redundant.

Someone speculated that an Application-Server (JBoss) might not be for handling Data and an Apache would be the better fit for it.

Could someone help me out on this? Or point me into the right direction what I should google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out there is no Apache-Server (B). The data gets synchronized between the JBoss and the Apache-Server (A).

So all my suspicion was appropriate :)